# How do I import the Dropbox SDK into a Google App Engine application?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, dropbox

I want the line

```
import dropbox
```

to work. I downloaded the Python Core API from Dropbox, and copied the contents of the zip file into my (otherwise working) app's folder. When I run my app, it gives me the following error:

```
ERROR    2013-08-07 19:47:04,111 wsgi.py:219] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/myusername/Downloads/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 196, in Handle
handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
File "/home/myusername/Downloads/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 255, in _LoadHandler
handler = __import__(path[0])
File "/home/myusername/Downloads/appname/appname.py", line 1, in <module>
import dropbox
File "/home/myusername/Downloads/appname/dropbox/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
from . import client, rest, session
File "/home/myusername/Downloads/appname/dropbox/client.py", line 14, in <module>
from .rest import ErrorResponse, RESTClient
File "/home/myusername/Downloads/appname/dropbox/rest.py", line 7, in <module>
import pkg_resources
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources
```

How do I resolve this error?

Answer (score 1):

As indicated by the link posted by @Tim Dierks, you can solve this issue by creating a pkg_resouces module within the dropbox folder with the contents

```
def resource_filename(*args): 
    cert_path =  '/path/to/trusted-certs.crt'
    return cert_path
```

As far as I can tell, pkg_resources only needs one method that returns the path to a certificate. trusted-certs.crt should be in your dropbox source folder.

Answer (score 0):

You need to also package and distribute the pkg_resources module into your App Engine app. However, from what I've seen elsewhere, you'll run into some other challenges thereafter. It looks like the answers to [Writing files to Dropbox account from GAE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9350634/writing-files-to-dropbox-account-from-gae) have gotten this working (for put, anyway).